# Building a language translation tool for smart phones

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, windows-7

I am implementing a language conversion tool, to convert Spanish to English, on a variety of smart phones: Android, BlackBerry, iPhone, Windows Phone 7.

How do I implement language conversions?  Searching, I am not finding a tutorial about this, and I don't having any experience with this.

Comment: This question is well beyond the scope of programming.  You need a domain expert on language translation to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Language translation is hard to get right so you may want to lean on an existing language translation service. Services such as Google translate offer APIs and you could try calling into from your mobile application if it meets your requirements.  Language conversion is a sub-field of computational linguistics and it ins't a solved problem though there are techniques you can read about.

Blog entry about Googles translation API http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/03/google-launched-another-ajax-api-this.html